# Angular - issue looping with an ng-container

Tags: angular, angular5, ng-template, ng-container

I want to call an ng-template from within a ngFor using an ng-container

My list is an array and has a list of objects. one property of an object is title - seen in the ng-template.

**Html:**

```
<ul>

    <li *ngFor='let item of list;let i = index'>

        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate;context:item"></ng-container>

    </li>

</ul>

<ng-template #itemTemplate let-item="item">
    <p>{{ item?.title }}</p>
</ng-template>
```

Note: Issue is the let-item seems to be undefined or an empty object.
which is strange since im passing it in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of the `templateOutletContext` is slightly wrong.

You could use the `$implicit` key for the context and then bind it to you template like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of list">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate; context: { $implicit: item }">
    </ng-container>
  </li>
</ul>
<ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
    <p>{{ item?.title }}</p>
</ng-template>
```

or with a named key:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of list">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate; context: { item: item }">
    </ng-container>
  </li>
</ul>
<ng-template #itemTemplate let-item="item">
    <p>{{ item?.title }}</p>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! For anyone wondering, if you use an index in your *ngFor loop you can pass the index the same way:

`<li *ngFor="let fruit of fruitlist, let i=index">
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="fruitAccordion; context: { $implicit: fruit, $implicit: i }"></ng-container>`

`<ng-template #fruitAccordion let-fruit let-i></ng-template>`

Comment: You can not pass the same key more than once into the context, you need to assign it to a different key, e.g.: `context: { $implicit: fruit, myIndex: i }` and `let-i="myIndex"`

Comment: Ay! it looked like it's working but you're right

Answer (score 0):

First of all you element has to be inside scope of *ngFor. like if you want to repeat a

tag inside  tag. then the code would be

```
<div *ngFor="item in items">
  <p>{{item}}</p>
</div>
```

Similarly in your case  has to be inside

tag

```
<ul>

    <li *ngFor='let item of list;let i = index'>

        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate;context:item"></ng-container>
<ng-template #itemTemplate let-item="item">
    <p>{{ item?.title }}</p>
</ng-template>

    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let i of list">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate; context: { i: i }">
    </ng-container>
  </li>
</ul>
<ng-template #itemTemplate let-item="i">
    <p>{{ i?.title }}</p>
</ng-template>
```